# Simple Induction Proof

Tags: induction

How would one go about proving that 
$$0<\frac{n}{n+1}<1$$ by mathematical induction?

If $p(n)$ is the statement as above, then I know we show $p(1)$, and assume $p(n)$, but in this particular case I am not sure know to show $p(n+1)$.

Comment: That's not a very interesting thing to do by induction, basically $n$ is always less than $n+1$, QED...  Where did the problem come from?

Comment: Just a problem my tutor gave me, I now see why it's so easy ... Surprised I was so confused by it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inductive step, we need to show that
$$0<\frac{n}{n+1} < 1 \implies 0 < \frac{n+1}{n+2}<1$$
We do this in two parts:

1. Since $n>0$, we trivially have $\frac{n+1}{n+2}>0$ as a ratio of two positive integers.
2. We can rewrite the right-hand side of our inductive hypothesis as
   $$n < n+1$$
   (As above, $n+1>0$ so we don't need to worry about signs.)

   It’s easy to get from here to $n+1 < n+2$, and then dividing by $n+2$ gives $\frac{n+1}{n+2}<1$.

We conclude that
$$0<\frac{n+1}{n+2}<1,$$
as required.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Prove by induction that $0<n<n+1$ for each positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

One more way for the last step: notice that $\frac{n+1}{n+2} = \frac{n+2-1}{n+2} = 1-\frac{1}{n+2}<1 \ \forall n$ because the $\frac{1}{n+2}$ term is strictly positive.